# Reading serialised object java gives classnotfound exception

Tags: java, serialization, classnotfound

Here's my current code:

```
//export method
public static void exportObj (Object obj, String fname) {
    try {
        // Serialize data object to a file
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fname));
        out.writeObject(obj);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
//import method
public static Object importObj (String fname) {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fname));
        return in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return new Object();
}
```

The export function works fine, I think, it turns my `User` object into a file and saves it, but then when I try to import it, it gives me a ClassNotFound Exception. What is happening?

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` for which class?

Comment: ObjectInputStream. It gives it on the .readObject();.

Comment: No, post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the classes you want to deserialize must exist on the CLASSPATH of the project that contains the import code.

Comment: Wait, so like, I have to have the `User` class in the same folder as the import code?

Comment: No, you have to have the class available in the CLASSPATH, as he already told you.